# How to end program in a do-while (C++)

Tags: c++, debugging, do-while

Here is my code. I am trying to get the entire program to end if it goes into the second `if` statement inside the `do-while` loop. But every time I run it, it crashes. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int myData[10];
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        myData[i] = 1;
        cout<<myData[i];
    }
    
    do{
        int i;
        cout<<endl<<"Input index: ";
        cin>> i;
        
        int v;
        cout<<endl<<"Input value: ";
        cin>>v;
        
        if(i>=0||i<10){
            myData[i]=v;
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
                cout<<myData[i]<<" ";
            }
        }
        
        if (i<0||i>=10){
            cout<<"Index out of range. Exit.";
            return 0;
        }
        
    }while(1);
}
```

Comment: `if(i>=0||i<10){` Think about which numbers are either greater than zero or less than ten. I'm sure you realise that is true of **all** numbers. What you meant to write is `if(i>=0&&i<10){`

Comment: yea i realized i forgot in my code i have " return 0; " in the second if statement. i just added it

Comment: The program has to crash with an index-out-of-bounds type error in one of the two places where you attempt access myData[i]=. I would check your counters.

Comment: Thank you John that was it. I was struggling trying to figure it out I didn't catch that mistake. Thanks again!

Comment: @Ryan For future reference, StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a debugging service. You are expected to do your own debugging. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), for instance.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I will keep that in mind however I did ask a question regarding how to end my program but thanks to the commenters I realized there was an error in my code. But thank you I will keep this in mind and word my questions better in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(i>=0||i<10){
```

Think about which numbers are either greater than zero or less than ten. I'm sure you realise that is true of all numbers. What you meant to write is

```
if(i>=0&&i<10){
```

This explains your crash, you are accessing the `myData` array with an index that is outside the array bounds.

It's very common for beginners to get `&&` and `||` confused especially where there is negation involved as well.

Answer (score 0):

Other people have told you the problem:

```
    if(i>=0||i<10){
```

I'm going to explain why you hit this. You hit it because you didn't use any whitespace.

```
    if (i >= 0 && i < 10) {
```

Please, please, please, for all that is good in the world, use whitespace liberally. You absolutely will have fewer bugs, because my version is far easier to read. Furthermore if you work with older developers (like me) we can actually read your code far more easily.

Comment: not using whitespace made the OP use the wrong operator?

Comment: Enclosing comparisons inside parens will also help:  `((i >= 0) && (i < 10))`.

Comment: The compiler doesn't care about whitespace

Comment: While I agree spaces (and good formatting in general) make the code easier to read, I don't see how it is relevant to the OP. More of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Not using whitespace makes the || operator a LOT harder to see. Bugs hide when our eyes don't catch them readily. Is that absolutely why there was a bug? Possibly not, but it contributed to my having to read the code twice before I saw it.